# C implementation of linear search,interpolation search and binary search

Tags: arrays, c

I am a beginner in C and I need help.
What I am trying to do is make an array between (1-100). One of the number in the array will gone and it call missing number.
The output will be the "missing number" in the array.
I need to demonstrate the the implementation of linear search, interpolation search and binary search to solve the problem.

The problem is the output always same with the array which has been declared. It was fun playing with coding but I really need help to solve this task.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int MissingNum(int a[], int n)
{
    int i, total;
    total = (n + 1) * (n + 2) / 2;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        total -= a[i];
    return total;
}

int LS(int arr[], int n, int x)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        if (arr[i] == x)
            return i;
    return -1;
}

int BS(int arr[], int l, int r, int x)
{
    if (r >= l) {
        int mid = l + (r - l) / 2;

        if (arr[mid] == x)
            return mid;

        if (arr[mid] > x)
            return BS(arr, l, mid - 1, x);

        return BS(arr, mid + 1, r, x);
    }
    return -1;
}

int IS(int arr[], int lo, int hi, int x)
{
    int pos;
    
    if (lo <= hi && x >= arr[lo] && x <= arr[hi]) {

        pos = lo + (((double)(hi - lo) / (arr[hi] - arr[lo])) * (x - arr[lo]));

        if (arr[pos] == x)
            return pos;

        if (arr[pos] < x)
            return IS(arr, pos + 1, hi, x);

        if (arr[pos] > x)
            return IS(arr, lo, pos - 1, x);
    }
    return -1;
}


int main(void)
{
    int choice;
    int arr[] = {86, 56, 95, 59, 18, 91, 73, 80, 31, 87, 84, 51, 16, 27, 40, 60, 26, 20, 6, 92, 25,100,
                48, 90, 15, 96, 69, 71, 76, 47, 74, 49, 63, 38, 33, 3, 55, 14, 45, 46, 30, 35, 53, 50,
                62, 39, 42, 10, 88, 17, 77, 9, 72, 81, 37, 82, 21, 61, 43, 78, 23, 58, 83, 12, 54, 13,
                89, 1, 24, 7, 99, 64, 93, 5, 57, 29, 41, 94, 34, 44, 36, 85, 4, 68, 22, 28, 75, 66, 65,
                11, 19, 97, 70, 79, 8, 52, 32, 9, 8, 2, 67};

    int x = MissingNum(arr,99);
    int n = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);
    int process;

    do
    {


    printf("\t\tMissing integer is %d\n\n", x);
    printf("Choose your type of search\n");
    printf("1. Linear search\n");
    printf("2. Binary search\n");
    printf("3. Interpolation search\n\n");
    printf("Insert input: ");
    scanf("%d",&process);


    switch (process)     {
  
     case 1 :  {
        clock_t countstart = clock();
        int result = LS(arr, n, x);
        int length = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
        printf("List of Integers : \n");
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)  {
                printf("%d ", arr[i]);
            }

        if (result == -1)
        {
          printf(" \n\nMissing Integer : %d \n", x);
        }
        clock_t countstop = clock();
        printf("\n\nExecution for Linear Search: %f seconds\n", (double)(countstop - countstart) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
        }
        break;

    case 2 : {
        clock_t countstart = clock();
        int output = BS(arr, 0, n - 1, x);
        int length = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
        printf("List of Integers : \n");
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
            {
                printf("%d ", arr[i]);
            }

            if (output == -1)
            {
                printf(" \n\nBinary Search Integer : %d \n",x);
            }
            clock_t countstop = clock();
            printf("\n\nExecution time for Binary Search: %f seconds\n", (double)(countstop - countstart) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);


        }
        break;

    case 3 :{
        clock_t countstart = clock();
        int index = IS(arr, 0, n - 1, x);
        int length = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);

        printf("List of Integers : \n");
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
            {
                printf("%d ", arr[i]);
            }

            if (index == -1)
            {
                printf(" \n\nInterpolation Search Integer : %d \n",x);
            }
            clock_t countstop = clock();
            printf("\n\nExecution time for Interpolation Search: %f seconds\n", (double)(countstop - countstart) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

        }

        break;
   
    default : printf("Invalid code please try again");
    break;
}
        printf("\n\nDo you want to continue? Enter '1' if YES and '2' if NO : ");
        scanf(" %d" ,&choice);
        }while(choice==1);
        getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please take some time to read the [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). As your question stands now there is insufficient information to be able to help you.

Comment: Specifically add actual output and expected output. Also do you want to randomize missing value in array or are you asking something else?

Comment: The array is not sorted. The first thing I would expect your code to do is sorting it. Ideally in a function.

Comment: Actually there are 101 initializer values. At least `8` and `9` are included twice.

Comment: I seem to have micounted 100. And yes, 8 and 9 twice. By the way, conscious use of white space and newlines (i.e. aligned columns in init list) would have helped with counting.

Comment: I do admire your `MissingNum()` however. Nifty - if the assumptions are met by the array size and init....

Comment: Bob, I think you have a reasonable chance to improve your queston to the point where you get another upvote. See the comments (including other users than me) above. expected in and out for example, indentation, more explicitly stressing what it is that puzzles you in your observation (mention why "always the same" is so odd). If you do that well, the error might become painfully obvious. That is a good thing, resist the temptation to hide the mistake. Improving the question in hindsight is a good thing. Explain the thinking of your code (especially MissingNum offering its result as parameter).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please double check `, 9, 8,` for typos. I suspect you want `,`  there.
With `, 98,` you'd have a cleanly initialised 100 entry array, without a missing number.
With `,`  you'd have a 99 entry array with 98 missing.

I tried and with that typo fix all three algos result in 98 being found.
Replacing a different of the init numbers with 98 then results in that number being found by all three algos.

Your implementations seem questionable to me.

LS looks through the array to check whether the number provided from outside is missing and confirms if it is. That is not actually finding the missing number. For IS and BS practically the same.

Whatever number `MissingNum()` guesses (and guesses incorrectly), as long as it is not in the array (which is true for anything beyond 100), all three algos will confirm. `MissingNum()` is guessing incorrectly, because it makes assumptions on the array init (one missing, all others once), which the shown array init does not match. When I tried the guess was 150, probably the same for you. Obviously wrong. The fact that all algos confirm that guess, should have made you suspicious. Fixing the typo as I proposed fixes `MissingNum()`s assumptions. It guess correctly (98) and all three algos enthusiastically agree - they should be tarred and feathered.

Comment: I found my answer by playing with the init list....

Comment: By the way, I suspect your implementation is cheating.  
They more or less work like the old magician trick.

Magician:  "I thought of a secret number. I will telepathically transmit it to a volunteer from the audiency. You just need to guess."
Volunteer: "Umm, 98?"
Magician:  "Exactly!! Admire the greatness of my telepathy."

Comment: :-) Moving the typoed `, 9, 8` to the end of the init also seems to help. Because you hardcoded the correct number of inits, 99, somewhere else....  in spite of the fact that you demonstrate awareness of `sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0])`...